# Count rows for each distinct city

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

Hi everyone after being able to pull the data from the database by city,now I want to group and count the places within that city.Here is the output of the places within the city.
City is CAPE TOWN

Places are

```
belhar,Tygervalley,Camps bay,Hout Bay,belhar,hout bay,bellville,Tygerberg,Tygervelley,Camps bay,camps bay,robben Island
```

My goal is to have output like

```
 belhar=2,Tygervalley=3,Camps bay=3,Hout bay=2,
bellville=1,Tygerberg=1,Tygervalley=1,robben island=1
```

Meanig I have `Place = Number` of counts of that place.

Answer (score 1):

If you get array of places then you can group and count them by looping and storing results in an array

```
$results=[];
foreach($places and $place) {
  if(!array_key_exists($place, $results))
    $results[$place]=1;
  else 
    $results[$place]+=1;
}
```

Comment: I think I should use this but using javascript of which is bit tricky.I tried to code the above script using javascript i am getting errors any Idea on how can i turn ur code in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select city, count(*) as c FROM yourtable GROUP BY City
```